# Calling functions from different classes

Tags: java, list

I'm writing a program and I'm supposed to check and see if a certain object is in the list before I call it. I set up the `contains()` method which is supposed to use the `equals()` method of the `Comparable` interface I implemented on my `Golfer`  class but it doesn't seem to call it (I put print statements in to check). I can't seem to figure out whats wrong with the code, the `ArrayUnsortedList` class I'm using to go through the list even uses the correct `toString()` method I defined in my `Golfer` class but for some reason it won't use the `equals()` method I implemented.

```
//From "GolfApp.java"    
public class GolfApp{
ListInterface <Golfer>golfers = new ArraySortedList<Golfer> (20);
Golfer golfer;
//..*snip*..
if(this.golfers.contains(new Golfer(name,score)))
    System.out.println("The list already contains this golfer");
else{
    this.golfers.add(this.golfer = new Golfer(name,score));
    System.out.println("This golfer is already on the list");
}

//From "ArrayUnsortedList.java"
protected void find(T target){
    location = 0;
    found = false;

    while (location < numElements){
        if (list[location].equals(target))  //Where I think the problem is                       
        {
            found = true;
            return;
        }
        else 
            location++;
    }
 }

 public boolean contains(T element){
    find(element);
    return found;
 }


//From "Golfer.java"    
public class Golfer implements Comparable<Golfer>{
//..irrelavant code sniped..//
public boolean equals(Golfer golfer)
{
    String thisString = score + ":" +  name;  
    String otherString = golfer.getScore() + ":" + golfer.getName() ;
    System.out.println("Golfer.equals() has bee called");

    return thisString.equalsIgnoreCase(otherString);
}

public String toString()
{
    return (score + ":" + name);
}
```

My main problem seems to be getting the find function of the `ArrayUnsortedList` to call my equals function in the `find()` part of the `List` but I'm not exactly sure why, like I said when I have it printed out it works with the `toString()` method I implemented perfectly.

I'm almost positive the problem has to do with the `find()` function in the `ArraySortedList` not calling my `equals()` method. I tried using some other functions that relied on the `find()` method and got the same results.

Comment: Does your Golfer class actually implement Comparable?  For example: "public class Golfer implements Comparable"

Comment: Yeah I should have included that like I did with the variables at the top. It acutally uses Generics for it too which I don't totaly understand yet, I'm not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: Is something preventing you from stepping through your code to see what's going on?

Comment: It turns out I the equals() method has to be in the form equals(Object objName) since it inherits from Object. I actually did run through it quite a few times though before I asked here :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `equals` method should take an Object argument, not a Golfer. The `equals(Golfer)` method is overloading the `Comparable`'s `equals(Object)` method but does not implement it. It's simply an overloaded method no other code knows about, so it doesn't get called.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    if(!(obj instanceof Golfer)) return false;

    Golfer golfer = (Golfer)obj;
    String thisString = score + ":" +  name;  
    String otherString = golfer.getScore() + ":" + golfer.getName() ;
    System.out.println("Golfer.equals() has bee called");

    return thisString.equalsIgnoreCase(otherString);
}
```